# "Not found. Authentication passthru(Azure)" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, azure-active-directory

I am getting "Not found. Authentication passthru(Azure)"  error when i try to login with Azure Id option.Can please help how to resolve this issue?

I’m currently getting the following error: Not found. Authentication passthru.

Accompanied with:

```
Url: http://localhost:3000/users/auth/azure_activedirectory_v2

Started GET "/users/auth/azure_activedirectory_v2" for ::1 at 2021-02-16 07:15:51 +0000
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru as HTML
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
```

Routes:

```
devise_for :users,
                  
                 controllers: {
                    sessions:           'users/sessions',
                    omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
                  }
```

Below the gem I am using:

```
gem 'omniauth-azure-activedirectory-v2'
```

Initializers Configuration

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.omniauth :azure_activedirectory_v2,
                  client_id:     ENV['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'],
                  client_secret: ENV['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
                  tenant_id:     ENV['AZURE_TENANT_ID'],
```

Comment: try use this `<%= link_to "Login", user_azure_activedirectory_v2_omniauth_authorize_path(prompt: 'select_account'), method: :post %>`

Comment: Thanks.Issue already fixed.Issue with omniauth version.

Comment: Hi do you mind posting an answer so that this issue can be treated as archived?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed issue by updating gem file as below.

```
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.1'
```